# js merge values of array of objects with same key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and I would like to merge all names into one array with a one liner.

```
[{
   id:1,
   name: 'peter'
},
{
  id:2,
  name: 'john'
}]
```

expected output:

```
['peter', 'john']
```

Comment: There's nothing _"merged"_ in your requirement. You only extract the value of a common property.

Comment: `const arr2 = arr1.map(({name}) => name)`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to create another array with the list of names:

```
const people = [{
   id:1,
   name: 'peter'
},
{
  id:2,
  name: 'john'
}];

const names = people.map(({ name }) => name);
```

Comment: This is an obvious, often-repeated duplicate question. It's not useful to post answers to them. Please vote to close as duplicate instead.